# Grunt - how can I specify files to multiple targets in the same task?

Tags: gruntjs

I have 2 `sass` targets. 
one creates debug info, the other does not.

If I don't copy/paste the files section between the targets, it doesn't seem to work.

```
sass: {
  server: {
    options: {
      debugInfo: true
    },
    files: {
      '.tmp/styles/main.css': '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/main.scss'
    }
  },
  dist: {

    files: {
      '.tmp/styles/main.css': '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/main.scss'
    }
  }
},
```

How can I reuse the files decleration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a grunt-sass point of view, you can't share the file declaration between multiple targets.

But to avoid duplication in your Gruntfile, you can always use plain old Javascript variables:

```
var cssFiles = {
  '.tmp/styles/main.css': '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/main.scss'
}
// ...
grunt.initConfig({
  // ...
  sass: {
    server: {
      options: {debugInfo: true},
      files: cssFiles
    },
    dist: {
      files: cssFiles
    }
  },
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I guess that is the only option. If there's a way to specify it as part of the sass configuration, I would have preferred that answer.